# How can I turn off Jupyter cells ("#In [2]") in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

Can somebody explain what is "#In [2]" for example in python? Pycharm to be precise.

(In case it is important, this code that I run was previously written using Jupyter, but I transferred it as .py to pycharm)

[image]

I know that its not good to upload screens, but its more environment related than code related. Or explain please why it is better to have it in your code, rather than removing it.

I don't want to have such cells in my code and I really want to turn it off, but I don't even know how it is called to look for info about it. Its not written in the code, but it does not let my code run as one, rather just parts of code.

Comment: Are you using a Juypter notebook? This is pretty conventional for Juypter notebooks to keep track of what was run and what sequence it was run in.  This indicates that it's the second thing (which was an input) run against your notebook, and there would be a follow-up Out (which would be the third thing run against your notebook).

Comment: @Makoto , no. I try to read my colleague's code and I have to redo/fix it. I transferred it to pycharm  in .py extension and I still get those "cells".

Comment: You're clearly running a notebook-ish/Jupyter-ish tool; this is what that tool _does_. If you don't want it, don't use that tool.

Comment: Unless your `.py` file contains a literal `# In[2]:` comment in its text, of course, in which case you can just delete it. :) -- I don't know (haven't looked into) what exporting a Jupyter notebook as Python source looks like, but if what you have is Pycharm recognizing comments created by Jupyter during the export and treating them as sections, as long as they're just text and not maintained by Pycharm on your behalf you can just delete them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. do you know how to delete all of this "comments"? Because i have like 100 cells or something and i just thought that it is some kind of particular "view" that can be changed all together

Comment: You can tell whether or not it's a view by opening the file in a text editor and seeing if they're still there. If they are, text-oriented tools are appropriate. For example, in my editor of choice -- Helix -- I'd write `%s^[#] In\[[[:digit:]]+\]:.*`, press enter, and then press `d` twice to delete the selections and their following newlines. You could probably do something similar with grep.